# breaking a bigger data frame into smaller ones based on a keys from list of keys in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have been stuck with a task for quite a while. I have a data frame which consists of different keys and units for each of them spanning over weeks. 
I need to break this data frame into smaller chunks of data frames where each frame consists of values with the same key so that this one bigger data frame becomes a list of data frames.

For example, let the bigger data frame be

```
KEY UNITS   WEEK    YEAR
A-1  42      2      2019
A-1  24      3      2019
A-1  29      5      2019
A-1  36      6      2019
A-2  27      2      2019
A-2  46      3      2019
A-2  44      4      2019
B-1  53      2      2019
B-1  31      4      2019
B-1  25      5      2019
B-1  52      6      2019
B-1  30      8      2019
B-2  46      2      2019
B-2  38      3      2019
B-2  36      4      2019
```

And I would like to break this data frame into a list of data frames where the key remains unique through each individual data frame like below:

```
KEY UNITS   WEEK    YEAR        KEY UNITS   WEEK    YEAR        KEY UNITS   WEEK    YEAR
A-1  30      2      2019        A-2  43      2      2019        B-1  24      2      2019
A-1  43      3      2019        A-2  54      3      2019        B-1  47      4      2019
A-1  25      5      2019        A-2  54      4      2019        B-1  53      5      2019
A-1  29      6      2019                                        B-1  25      6      2019
```

and

```
KEY UNITS   WEEK    YEAR
B-1 41       8      2019
B-2 54       2      2019
B-2 44       3      2019
B-2 33       4      2019
```

and obtain all these data frames as a list of data frames.

Now I have tried to do it using the code snippet below but it has performance issues as my number of unique keys are very large:

```
ds1<-list()
for (j in 1:num_of_unique_keys)
{
 ds1[[j]]<-subset(dataset, dataset$KEY==extkeys[j])
}
head(ds1[[2]])
```

here 'num_of_unique_keys' is the total count of how many unique keys are there in the bigger data frame, 'dataset' is the data set i am working on, 'extkeys' is the list of unique keys in the dataset and 'ds1' be the list of data frames I want to obtain as the output.
I know the performance issue is majorly because of the for loop which are a no-go in R but I have simply not been able to find another efficient method to solve this problem.

I would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in Base-R

```
split(dataset, dataset$KEY)
```

Output:

```
$`A-1`
  KEY UNITS WEEK YEAR
1 A-1    42    2 2019
2 A-1    24    3 2019
3 A-1    29    5 2019
4 A-1    36    6 2019

$`A-2`
  KEY UNITS WEEK YEAR
5 A-2    27    2 2019
6 A-2    46    3 2019
7 A-2    44    4 2019

$`B-1`
   KEY UNITS WEEK YEAR
8  B-1    53    2 2019
9  B-1    31    4 2019
10 B-1    25    5 2019
11 B-1    52    6 2019
12 B-1    30    8 2019

$`B-2`
   KEY UNITS WEEK YEAR
13 B-2    46    2 2019
14 B-2    38    3 2019
15 B-2    36    4 2019
```

Comment: Thank you. Didnt think it could be done so simply. I was trying more to learn lapply somehow. But this is even better. Thnk you so much :)

Comment: You're welcome. You can practice your lapply by working with the output of the split. for example `lapply(split_data, function(x) mean(x$UNITS) )`

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
lapply(unique(dataset[, "KEY"]), function(x) {
  tempDf <- dataset[dataset[, "KEY"] %in% x, ]

  return(tempDf)

}))
```

Note that this easily generalizes in case you want to split according to `WEEK` or something else by means of

```
columns = c("KEY", "WEEK")
map(columns, function(a)  lapply(unique(dataset[, a]), function(x) {
      tempDf <- dataset[dataset[, a] %in% x, ]

      return(tempDf)

    }))
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understand you correctly you want a different dataframe per KEY

```
df <- tribble(~KEY, ~UNITS,   ~WEEK,    ~YEAR,
"A-1",  42,      2,      2019,
"A-1",  24,      3,      2019,
"A-1",  29,      5,      2019,
"A-1",  36,      6,      2019,
"A-2",  27,      2,      2019,
"A-2",  46,      3,      2019,
"A-2",  44,      4,      2019,
"B-1",  53,      2,      2019,
"B-1",  31,      4,      2019,
"B-1",  25,      5,      2019,
"B-1",  52,      6,      2019,
"B-1",  30,      8,      2019,
"B-2",  46,      2,      2019,
"B-2",  38,      3,      2019,
"B-2",  36,      4,      2019)


map(unique(df$KEY), ~{
  df %>% filter(KEY == .x)
}) %>% set_names(nm = unique(df$KEY))
```